# Efficient way of dividing a column by the mean of given groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with hourly values for several years. My dataframe is already in datetime format, and the column containing the values is called say "value column".

```
date  = ['2015-02-03 23:00:00','2015-02-03 23:30:00','2015-02-04 00:00:00','2015-02-04 00:30:00']
value_column = [33.24  , 31.71  , 34.39  , 34.49 ]

df = pd.DataFrame({'value column':value_column})
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['index'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df.drop(['index'],axis=1,inplace=True)

print(df.head())
                   value column  
index                                     
2015-02-03 23:00:00  33.24   
2015-02-03 23:30:00  31.71   
2015-02-04 00:00:00  34.39   
2015-02-04 00:30:00  34.49
```

I know how to get the mean of the "value column" for each year efficiently with for instance the following command:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.year).mean()
```

Now, I would like to divide all hourly values of the column "value column" by the mean of its values for its corresponding year (for instance dividing all the 2015 hourly values by the mean of 2015 values, and same for the other years).

Is there an efficient way to do that in pandas?

Expected result:

```
                   value column   Value column/mean of year
index                                     
2015-02-03 23:00:00  33.24             0.993499  
2015-02-03 23:30:00  31.71             0.94777
2015-02-04 00:00:00  34.39             1.027871
2015-02-04 00:30:00  34.49             1.03086
```

Many thanks,

Comment: `Is there an efficient way to do that in pandas?` - most likely there is.

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks @Peslier..Do note that re-indexing or apply functions won't be required if inbuilt 'transformation' function is utilized. It is meant to solve specifically the kind of problems that you stated, optimally in a succinct manner. Best JALO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
df = (df.set_index(df.index.year)/df.groupby(df.index.year).mean()).set_index(df.index)
```

So you set the index to be the year in order to divide by the `groupby` object, and then reset the index to keep the original timestamps.

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

dr = pd.date_range('1-1-2010','1-1-2020', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'value column':np.random.rand(len(dr))}, index=dr)
print(df, '\n')
print(df.groupby(df.index.year).mean(), '\n')

df = (df.set_index(df.index.year)/df.groupby(df.index.year).mean()).set_index(df.index)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
#original data
                     value column
2010-01-01 00:00:00      0.417022
2010-01-01 01:00:00      0.720324
2010-01-01 02:00:00      0.000114
2010-01-01 03:00:00      0.302333
2010-01-01 04:00:00      0.146756
                          ...
2019-12-31 20:00:00      0.530828
2019-12-31 21:00:00      0.224505
2019-12-31 22:00:00      0.459977
2019-12-31 23:00:00      0.931504
2020-01-01 00:00:00      0.581869

[87649 rows x 1 columns] 

#grouped by year
      value column
2010      0.497135
2011      0.503547
2012      0.501023
2013      0.497848
2014      0.497065
2015      0.501417
2016      0.498303
2017      0.499266
2018      0.499533
2019      0.492220
2020      0.581869 

#final output
                     value column
2010-01-01 00:00:00      0.838851
2010-01-01 01:00:00      1.448952
2010-01-01 02:00:00      0.000230
2010-01-01 03:00:00      0.608150
2010-01-01 04:00:00      0.295203
                          ...
2019-12-31 20:00:00      1.078436
2019-12-31 21:00:00      0.456107
2019-12-31 22:00:00      0.934494
2019-12-31 23:00:00      1.892455
2020-01-01 00:00:00      1.000000

[87649 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
df.groupby(df.index.year).transform(lambda x: x/x.mean())
```

Refer: [Group By: split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)

***Transformation is recommended as it is meant to perform some group-specific computations and return a like-indexed object.***

Answer (score 1):

I just found another way, which im not sure to understand but works!

```
df['result'] = df['value column'].groupby(df.index.year).apply(lambda x: x/x.mean())
```

I thought that in apply functions, x was refering to single values of the array but it seems that it refers to the group itself.